# Simple & effective way to update packages inherited from parent docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, upgrade

For my Docker-based app, I would like to quickly update all inherited packages `FROM` the parent image with the latest security patches.

I am fully aware, that the best practice here is to just run the build using the Dockerfile, this would automatically install all the latest packages, but unfortunately, this is not an option.

Is there any other quick & dirty way to achieve this besides doing the following?

```
FROM baseimage:1.0.0

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
```

Comment: I recommend changing version of your built image per update or use `docker-compose` beside `Dockerfile`. Did you try that?

Comment: @Saeed it is not the installed docker or docker-compose I am trying to update, it is the packages of the parent image WITHIN a `docker build` operation

Comment: I think you're doing the good practice. But if I were you, I would do this: `docker build -t image:new_version . && docker stop image:old_version && docker run -dpPORT:PORT image:new_version`. The reason is since the volume and everything are the same, that should face you no trouble (except incompatibility issues of newly upgraded versions of packages)